# Unreasonably high ping on Macbook Pro

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, macbook, iphone

I have issues which I am experiencing for more than a year now. Sometimes I can see that connection is just too slow. When I open bash and ping a random website in the country, I can see that ping is about 5000 instead of usual 30. Most of the time issue was my Iphone XR which is usually connected to the same WIFI network. If I disconnect the Iphone, problem disappears. In 5% of the cases, disconnecting Iphone won't improve the situation and I am stuck with this, until problem disappears by itself. I thought the issue may be Apple's Private Relay, which I did turn off on both devices, without improvement. I don't think it is Icloud either because I have nothing new that could be uploaded. Is there a way to see which process is creating this issue? I have found several other threads around the web, each without definite solution.

Comment: First stop - https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/